Different Number of Font Size Between in Console Properties and Registry
I see the PowerShell font size in the Properties is 28.
I used a script to check the font size via the registry, but the result was different, namely 1835025.
I don't know what type of number? and how do I get the same value as in properties (28).
I mean, convert 1835025 to 28.
I only want to get the console font size from the script whose value is exactly the same as in the properties.
Thank you.
$PS5Reg = "HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe"
(Get-ItemProperty $PS5Reg).FontSize

The Output is 1835025



On my Windows 10 Pro, PowerShell 7.4.2, there is no FontSize member for that registry entry. (Get-ItemProperty $PS5Reg) | Format-List * -Force.

Are you just trying to view the font size, or change it?  If you are trying to change it, then do you want to do it dynamically and on the fly as the PowerShell script runs, or are you wanting to change it so that it becomes the new font size every time PowerShell runs?  If you want PowerShell to start with a certain font size, you have to modify the shortcut file (*.lnk) that starts PowerShell.

-@Darin I want to get the console font size from the script whose value is exactly the same as in the properties.

What version of windows 10 are you?  I don't see that registry entry in 22H2, and I'm using powershell 5.1.  From process monitor, it seems like it saves the font size in the .lnk shortcut file itself.

-@js2010 Win 11 24H2

I don't see it in win11 22h2.

perhaps fontsize exist or not in registy after some my modify

Converting dec 1835025 to hex representation results in 1C0011. It's easily deducible that the high order word is hex 1C => dec 28. I assume some simple research could reveal the meaning of the low order word if needed.

Thanks. I tried change the size in properties with other number 24. After Restart, the registry value not changed, still  1835025 1C0011.
